# Why does a const std::vector apply const to the contained objects?

Tags: c++

I know that `const std::vector<int>` applies the `const` to the `int`s, too, (e.g. `begin() const` will return a `const_iterator`). I am curious as to the reason for this. In my mind it would make more sense to apply the `const` only to the vector (e.g. no resizing), and leave contained object's constness to them (e.g. `std::vector<const int>`).

Is there a good reason for this? If so, can someone please explain it to me? Or is it just an oversight from the original days of the STL that can't be corrected anymore because of backwards compatibility?

Comment: It's just a somewhat convention that if your Car is immutable, then its Wheels are too

Comment: @Baruch  This is by analogy with arrays. When you declare an array like const int a[] = { 1, 2, 3 }; then it means that its elements are constant.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow in that case you are declaring (following the rules for reading a variable deceleration) an array of "const int", which is fine

Comment: @AlexLarionov In the immutable cars where I am from, you can still change the channel on the radio

Comment: up until c++11 a `std::vector<const T>` was not allowed, so a `const vector<T>` was the only way to have a vector with `const` elements. After that the rules changed and I am not sure if `const T` elements are ok

Comment: @Baruch then the Car wasn't immutable?

Comment: @idclev463035818 - It wasn't allowed in C++11 either. C++17 *almost* allowed it (by happy coincidence), but still no. Not sure about C++20.

Comment: @StoryTeller I meant including C++11, with C++17 the rules are rather fuzzy and I don't really understand it

Comment: @Baruch What is a car? It's the chassis, the frame, the wheels, the engine, the seats.... etc. If the car is immutable then the components that make up the car must also be immutable -- otherwise the car isn't actually immutable.

Comment: @cdhowie But you can still put on your sunglasses if you are sitting in this car. You are not immutable, only the car is.

Comment: @Baruch Sure. But you aren't part of the car.

Comment: @cdhowie Exactly. The elements are not part of the vector, it is just a container holding them.

Comment: @Baruch Disagree. The vector _is_ its contents. Otherwise two vectors with different contents would compare as equal as long as they were the same size, or copying the vector would produce a same-size vector with default-initialized elements. I will append to my answer to address this point.

Comment: @Baruch I've added to my answer. Let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Const-ness in C++ is a semantic concept that means "the observable state of this object cannot be changed using this name."  In the case of a vector, its contents are considered part of its observable state, so if the vector is const then its elements necessarily are also const.

This also means you can give some other code a const reference to your vector and have some certainly that it's not going to change the vector on you (reference made explicit here for illustration):

```
std::vector<int> a = create_a_vector();
std::vector<int> const & b = a;
something_else(b);
```

Unless `something_else()` is deviously going to cast away the const qualifier, you can be sure that it won't be mutating the vector or its contents in any way.

If the type worked as you proposed, you would have to *copy* the vector:

```
std::vector<int> a = create_a_vector();
std::vector<const int> b = a;
something_else(b);
```

If the vector is huge, this would have quite a big impact on performance.

---

Addendum: The crux of the question seems to be "*why* are the contents of the vector part of the observable state?"

The best way I can explain this is to illustrate it through the following questions:

- If you copy a vector, do the elements get copied?
- If you compare two vectors for equality, are the elements compared, or just the properties of the vector (the size)?

If the answers to these questions are "yes" then the elements themselves are also part of the observable state.  So, this establishes a kind of rule: **whatever gets copied during copy-construction/assignment or compared during an equality test is part of the observable state of an object.**

For vector, the answers are "yes."  Therefore, the elements are considered part of the observable state of the vector, and they *must* be considered const if the vector itself is const.

Contrast this with `std::unique_ptr`. Only the pointer value itself is part of the observable state; the pointer value of a `const std::unique_ptr<int>` *cannot* be mutated, but the pointer target *can.*  This makes sense, because:

- (You can't copy a `std::unique_ptr`, so we can't consider this part of the test.)
- If you compare two `std::unique_ptr`s for equality, only the pointer value is actually compared; the value of the target is not.

Therefore, for `std::unique_ptr`, the value of the target is *not* part of the observable state and the const-ness of the `std::unique_ptr` object is irrelevant with regards to whether the pointer target can be mutated.

Comment: @George because you don't want to confuse C++98 programmers who are familiar with `const int * v` and  `int * const v` difference

Comment: @George It's not. The state of the target object is not considered part of the observable state of the pointer.

Comment: My intuition would be that an `std::vector<T>` would be castable to an `std::vector<const T>`, but this may be too complicated, which may be a good reason to not do it "my" way

Comment: @Baruch It _is_ castable, but that cast creates a copy.

Comment: @Baruch Or rather, I should say, in your proposed version of the type, it could be made castable but that would create a copy of the vector. It's not currently castable because `std::vector<const T>` is not allowed.